# Print values of array according to input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print values of list according to user input, i.e. if user inputs 3, it prints only elements 1, 2 and 3. If user inputs 5, it prints elements, 1,2,3,4 and 5. I Have written below code but it is giving me error:

```
var1 = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' , '5']
x = input('Enter the number of sites')
print('The values are', var1[1:x] )
```

This error is coming:

```
slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python3, the [`input` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input) returns a string, and since list indices can only be integers you get the error message.

To fix it, you should convert the result of the `input` function to an integer, like this:

```
var1 = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' , '5']
x = int(input('Enter the number of sites'))
print('The values are', var1[1:x])
```

You can format the string to be nicely separated by commas, for instance:

```
to_print = ', '.join(var[1: x]))
print('The values are', to_print)
```

Comment: It should be noted that a blank input would raise a `ValueError` here.